# Android - storing contacts in my own list for the app to access

Tags: android, android-contacts

My app let the user selects contacts from his contact list in order to perform an action on them. When the user selects a contact, I get the name + image + phone number and show it in a list inside the app.

I want to store this info/list somewhere internally so the app can access it the next time it opens. How/Where can I do this?

Comment: you can use shard preferences or internal storage as per your requirement and convinience.

Comment: I use SharedPreferences for "simple" data but not for recurrent one as a list of <something>. Unless there is a better way, I will generate a json out of the info and store it but I was wondering if there is an already dedicated way for such info.

Comment: you better go with sqlite database instead of shared preferences